# Can Textmate nicely indent HTML?

Tags: textmate, html

Does Textmate have a function to nicely indent HTML?

HTML Tidy indents it - but it seems to delete tags as well. (This isn't completely proper HTML, but still!)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal" xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.speechapi.com/static/lib/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.speechapi.com/static/lib/speechapi-1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <!-- All above disappears -->       
    <p>Test</p>
    <!-- All below disappears-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of html where tags are deleted as this is surprising

Comment: @Mark: Updated with code

Comment: @Casebash I tried Tidy with your code and for me it only added tags.  http://www.copypastecode.com/46216/

Comment: @calvera: Ensure your document type is set to HTML, not plain text

Comment: @Casebash - in the markup you give, what gets deleted? I could kind of understand what it's doing if (for instance) the empty `<title>` container is removed.

Comment: @Dory: Everything disappears!

Comment: @Casebash: it was set to html... FYI, from what I remember about the Tidy plugin for Notepad++, it's configured via a text file.  So maybe there's something wrong with the Tidy configuration.

Comment: @Casebash- *Everything* disappears? When you wrote that parts/tags were deleted, I pictured *some* stuff sticking around afterwards. Do you have a before/after example where only some parts get deleted?

Comment: @Dori: Updated example

Comment: @Casebash - if you try moving the `<body>` element inside the `<html>` element, what does Tidy do then? (don't forget the `</head>` tag before `<body>`)

Answer (score 21):

You can press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all then `Text->Indent Selection`.

Comment: Years of TextMate and never seen or used this feature... \o/

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a full XML formatting: it keeps mis-indented lines and does not split up tags on the same line onto separate lines. Using Textmate 2.0-rc.4.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `Bundles > HTML > Tidy` or the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Tidy doesn't just indent it - it also seems to delete parts of it as well!

Comment: Question was about indenting not tidying

Comment: Tidying also fails when there are some issues like unknown element names.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out something that crosses a bit the other answers:

If you select the text that you wish to format (or reindent), TextMate will apply specific actions only to that. So, if you <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> your document and then apply Tidy (either from the Bundles > HTML menu or with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut) it will mostly only do indenting, skipping alerts on validations (that sometimes are unnecessary since we might be working on page snippets).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcode or Dashcode instead if you install the Developer Tools. They come free on the install discs that came with your computer. I believe both Xcode and Dashcode have syntax highlighting.

If you want really good software, get [Coda.](http://www.panic.com/coda/) It is  a bit pricey at $100, but I would definitely say it is worth it. It has syntax highlighting and (the big part for me) autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Tidy call in TextMate's built-in HTML bundle can deal with your HTML.

TextMate's Bundles -> HTML -> Tidy produces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal" xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.speechapi.com/static/lib/swfobject.js">
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.speechapi.com/static/lib/speechapi-1.1.js">
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- All above disappears -->
        <p>
            Test
        </p><!-- All below disappears-->
    </body>
</html>
```

On your sample code. Nothing disappeared. You also get the following warnings:

```
line 1 column 1 - Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
line 2 column 5 - Warning: <body> isn't allowed in <head> elements
line 1 column 1 - Warning: <html> proprietary attribute "xmlns:tal"
line 1 column 1 - Warning: <html> proprietary attribute "xmlns:metal"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I experienced with the built-in `Text -> Indent Selection` or Tidy solution is that it doesn't play well with partial HTML code.  This is for example important when editing in WordPress or working with partials in Ruby on Rails.

The solution that worked for me was to add a command to the bundle with a custom Perl script by John Watson that I found here: http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=28256